# How to proceed past the collapsed pipe in Half Life: Opposing Force, chapter "Missing in Action", part of2a3

Tags: half-life-series

I went down the elevator shaft, turned off the power, climbed up to the top floor, into the vent, down through the collapsing pipe and found myself on the other side of the red door, the way forward blocked by a locked door with explosives right behind and a mighty wall of debris. So I'm stuck.

[This](http://www.livestream.com/badp/video?clipId=pla_dd7b6930-59f1-4ef4-ac5e-8a525f7ee001) is where I am precisely and what I've tried, but nothing seems to work to go past these barriers. (I apologize but Livestream seems to enjoy skipping up bits and pieces of the stream for some reason.)

Am I just looking in the wrong place? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Is "of2a3" the map name?

Comment: @Nick I believe it is. That's what the quicksaves and autosaves are named anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You previously had to push a small metal crate in order to climb onto the pipes and proceed on the opposite side of the red doors. Now you must push the same crate to the mighty debris blockade in order to crouch-jump onto them and proceed further into the game.

[image]